# Run code before Wordpress loads and insert data into WP if need be

Tags: php, plugin-development

I've done my requisite research and can't seem to find an ELEGANT way to do this.

We have a Wordpress app with some fairly intensive session management requirements and now need to run some old code before even loading Wordpress. I plan on initiating this process on the first line of the WP index.php file.

However, depending on the results of this old code, we may need to pass along a handful of key/value data from this process down to the plugin level in WP. What would be a good way to approach this? Thanks!

UPDATE (2017-01-19):

I just decided to use a local Redis instance to store any k/v data should the request need to proceed onward and load WP.

Comment: Store it in the database then get it back out of the database.

Answer (score 0):

Unless performance is a huge factor, or you need to change PHP session globals, you don't need to run anything before wordpress, just write a plugin that makes the checks needed on the `init` hook and `die()` if needed. This way you can also store the data wherever it is convenient for you.

For sure editing any wordpess core file is a big no-no which amount to forking wordpress with all the responsibilities it requires from you. The only file you may edit is `wp-config.php` but this should probably be done only if the plugin approach will not work

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty familiar with all the popular hooks. I should have mentioned that there are some performance issues. Since this legacy code is fairly "heavy", I wanted to avoid running Wordpress at all if it turned out that I didn't need to.

Comment: .... which bring the second part of the answer, you can do it out of wp-config.php

Comment: Indeed! That's where I'll introduce the legacy code I have to work with.

Answer (score 0):

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

Take a look at this list of hooks and call your **function** using the **hook** that you think is appropriate for your need.